# Solve Gray code for the intput range 62 < $input <= 65

Tags: php, gray-code

The following code show the gray code for upto last $input

```
function getGrayCode($n) {
    return $n ^ ($n >> 1);
 };

$input = 62;
$max = (1 << $input);
for( $i= $max- $input ; $i<$max; $i++) {
    printf("%s\n", decbin(getGrayCode($i)));   
}
```

The above code is working for $input value 62 but its not working for the rang 62 < $input <= 65. Can anyone solve it?

Comment: because of an integer overflow there - `$max = (1 << $input);` with $input >= 64

Comment: This smells like homework.

Comment: @splash58 - its ok for >=64 but it's not working 63bit as well.

Comment: `1` -  now bit at position 1, after 63 shifts it wil be at position 64 - it's `negative sign` bit